# removing the duplicates from a directory and saving them in another directory

Tags: python, image, duplicates

I am trying to find the duplicate images present in a directory and remove them from the original directory and save them in a different directory.Till now I am able to find the duplicate images,but I am not able to remove them from original folder and save the duplicate images in the new folder.

```
import sys
import os
import hashlib
dir ='/Users/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/cnf/duplicate_image'
uniquelist =[]
count = 0
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('image'):
  files = sorted(files)
  for filename in files:
    with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as f:
        im= f.read()
        hash=hashlib.md5(im).hexdigest()
        if hash not in uniquelist: 
            uniquelist.append(hash)
        else:
            print hash
```

Please help me how I can remove it from my original folder and save it to my new directory.Thanks a lot in advance. Apologies if it is a stupid question

Answer (score 4):

You can use shutil or os module. The syntax is something similar to

```
import os, shutil
os.rename("source", "destination")
#or
shutil.move("source", "destination")
```

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.